# Customize CSS in Wordpress plugin Widgets für Google Reviews from Trustindex.io

Tags: css, wordpress, google-reviews

I would like to customize the background of the Google reviews from the plugin **Widgets für Google Reviews** from Trustindex.io.

I can apply custom CSS changes in the developer console directly in the browser as follows:

```
.ti-widget.ti-goog .ti-review-item >.ti-inner {
    border-top-width: 2px !important;
    border-bottom-width: 2px !important;
    border-left-width: 2px !important;
    border-right-width: 2px !important;
    background-color: #bbbbbb !important; /*put here whatever I want*/
    color: green; /*test selector, which works*/
}
```

Strangely if I put that in the custom CSS of my theme OceanWP the color works, but the background won't.

Any idea what that could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra class to target that div. The original css of the widget already uses the `!important` tag and has an extra class so it trumps yours. Try targeting like this:

```
.ti-widget.ti-goog .ti-widget-container .ti-review-item >.ti-inner {
    border-top-width: 2px !important;
    border-bottom-width: 2px !important;
    border-left-width: 2px !important;
    border-right-width: 2px !important;
    background-color: #bbbbbb !important; /*put here whatever I want*/
    color: green; /*test selector, which works*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. I should re-learn CSS selectors...

Comment: Are .ti-widget.ti-goog and .ti-widget-container inherited from its parents?